# MVC partial view wtih different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have model as

```
public class MainDataViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Select Work Orders")]
    public string[] SelectedWorkOrdersValues { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList WorkOrderIds { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ORDERMASTER> ordersDetails;
}
```

And Main View as

```
@model InventoryEasy15.Models.MainDataViewModel
<div class="box-body">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                  
        <label for="fileToUpload">Select the Work Orders</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WorkOrderIds, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedWorkOrdersValues, Model.WorkOrderIds as MultiSelectList, new { id = "WorkOrders", @class = "form-control", data_placeholder = "Choose Work Orders..." })
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Get WorkOrder Details" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>


@Html.Partial("MainDataWorkOrderDetails", Model.ordersDetails)
```

And the Partial view as

```
@model IEnumerable<InventoryEasy15.ORDERMASTER>
<div id="myDisplayID"><div>
```

Now I am getting error as

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'InventoryEasy15.Models.MainDataViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[InventoryEasy15.ORDERMASTER]'.

Any thoughts.

The controller here is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MainDataWorkOrderDetails(MainDataViewModel m)
    {
        var model = new MainDataViewModel();
        var result = await db.ORDERMASTERs.Where(x => x.WOID == "WO7446708").ToListAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            model.ordersDetails = result;
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: The error means that `model.ordersDetails` is `null`. Suggest you add a default constructor to initialize it, or add a `else` block and include `else { model.orderDetails = new List<ORDERMASTER> }`. Side note: You can just use `Model.WorkOrderIds` in the `ListBoxFor()` method (no need for the `as MultiSelectList`)

Comment: I changed like this, if (result != null)
            {
                model.ordersDetails = result;
            } and it still fails
            else
            {
                model.ordersDetails = new List<ORDERMASTER>();
            }

Comment: Its unclear what you doing here. Why does your GET method have a parameter for a model (bad practice) and why is it returning a partial view?. But I repeat - the error means that that when you call `@Html.Partial("MainDataWorkOrderDetails", Model.ordersDetails)` the value of `Model.ordersDetails` is `null`. Debug your code!

Comment: I am trying to show search results using Ajax, and the List box selection will be used for filtering the model. And before the debug hits the get method, it failed with the error message. And more question, I have force to select any of the list box selection, how to do that?

Comment: Just add a default constructor as per my first comment so that `ordersDetails` will not be `null` when you first render the view - public MainDataViewModel() { ordersDetails = new List<ORDERMASTER>(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing model to the PartialView. Now, the model is of type `MainDataViewModel`, and your partial view expects the model of type `IEnumerable<InventoryEasy15.ORDERMASTER>`

> return PartialView(model);

I think you should consider passing model.orderDetails to the partial view from your action.

> return PartialView(model.orderDetails);

Or else, simply return the View containing the partial view if you want to pass the whole model